# Convert to numeric creates NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the pRMSE of two series. I therefore seperated them from a df and tried to calculate the Pr-coefficient via A.corr(B). I got the  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'. So I tried to convert them both to floats. There are only numbers between 0 and 1900 in both series. I used:

```py
completeA['avg'] = completeA['avg'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
completeA['min'] = completeA['min'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

but after doing that, there are many NaN values in my pd.Series. Here is an example of one row:

```py
    A = completeA['avg']
    print(A.loc[[482]])
              output:  482    1,000
    A = A.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    print(A.loc[[482]])
              output:  482    NaN
```

I have just noticed that all the valus that are changed to NaN are greater than 1000. Can pandas not convert values greater than 1000 to numeric? If not, how can I solve this?

Comment: that's probably due to the thousand comma in your data. Also, you should do `pd.to_numeric(completeA['avg'], errors='coerce')`, which is faster than `apply`.

Comment: yup, that was the issue. So simple. Thanks

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(pd.Series(['1','1,000','1.3']).str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce')` quick fix